# Mapping EVM Address to Substrate Address with Preserved Balance

Tags: substrate-node-template, evm, moonbeam, address

I'm working on a project involving an `EVM-compatible` Substrate blockchain and facing a challenge. The problem arises when trying to map `Ethereum-based` addresses, acquired through Metamask, to the corresponding Substrate addresses.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

I need to map an EVM address to a Substrate address.
The balance associated with the EVM address should also be reflected or accessible in the Substrate environment.
I understand that the cryptographic algorithms (`sr25519` or `ed25519` for Substrate and `secp256k1` for Ethereum) yield different addresses even with the same private key.

Any guidance, advice, or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked how moonbeam tackles this ? https://github.com/PureStake/moonbeam/blob/master/primitives/account/src/lib.rs

Comment: how can i use these codes ?